# Is putting a OR condition when Selecting/Displaying columns valid?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

new to SQL, I was wondering if its valid to put a "or" condition when choosing columns (SELECT)?

Example:

```
SELECT (Column1 OR Column2)
```

My Aim:
I'm currently creating a view that will display all claim types basic information that I will use for queries. Obviously, they are in different tables, so I was hoping to merge them into one view for easy access. The problem is when created the view puts the columns with OR statement to either a 1 or 0, when it should be a VARCHAR (string).

Full SQL Query:

```
CREATE VIEW ViewAllClaims AS
SELECT Claim.ClaimID, Claim.CreatedDate, (ReturnClaim.ClaimStatus or RepairClaim.ClaimStatus) as 'ClaimStatus', (SupplierName or FirstName) as 'Name'
FROM Claim, ReturnClaim, RepairClaim, Supplier, Product, ReturnClaimProduct, Customer
WHERE ( Claim.ClaimID = ReturnClaim.ClaimID
AND ReturnClaim.ClaimID = ReturnClaimProduct.ClaimID
AND ReturnClaimProduct.Keycode = Product.Keycode
AND Product.SupplierID = Supplier.SupplierID) 
or
(Claim.ClaimID = RepairClaim.ClaimID
AND RepairClaim.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID);
```

Screenshot of the result:
[image]

Comment: The `OR` is interpreted as boolean, its result is `true` or `false`, sp `1` or `0`... You want to use a conditional instead of a logical operator.

Comment: Thanks, its seems so obvious now that you point it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE`:

```
SELECT (
    CASE
    WHEN ReturnClaim.ClaimStatus IS NULL THEN RepairClaim.ClaimStatus
    ELSE ReturnClaim.ClaimStatus
    END
) AS 'ClaimStatus'
FROM ...
```